# Azure Fluent - Deployment Center Logs

Tags: azure, msdeploy

I'm using the Azure Fluent C# SDK and trying to get access to the Deployment Center logs that are located here:

[image]

Is anyone familiar as to if these logs are exposed in the Fluent API?

There is a class called:

[MSDeployLogEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.appservice.fluent.models.msdeploylogentry?view=azure-dotnet)

But I am not sure if this is associated with the Deployment Center logs.